# Chrome extension developement - Access localhost https with self-signed certificate flag deprecated since chrome version 88, what's the alternative?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, certificate, google-chrome-flags

I have developed a public chrome extension which connects to a game locally to display information from the game on a website. The game hosts a local https port with self-signed certificate. I have no control over the game - this is their method of allowing external tools to communicate with the game.
On chrome version 87 all users had to do is enable the flag chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and the extension would work. In chrome version 88 they have removed this flag, and temporarily users can chrome://flags/#temporary-unexpire-flags-m87 to be able to use the flag from version 87.
This option will probably not be available two chrome versions from now.

How should we do this? Is there a way to ask the user (with a single click) to trust the self-signed certificate of the game?

EDIT: Chrome has restored the #allow-insecure-localhost flag to version 88, so the question is no longer relevant.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1159077, the next update will restore the flag.

Comment: Great news, I guess it's solved then. Thank you!